# mongo aggregation with nested boolean

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I wish compute a mongo aggregation with nested boolean value to be summed.

first, my documents id like to compute looks like (in a simpler representation):

```
document 1
{
  key : 'value'
  ack: {isAck: True}
  ... : ...
}
document 2
{
  key : 'value'
  ack: {isAck: True}
  ... : ...
}

document 3
{
  key : 'value'
  ack: {isAck: True}
  ... : ...
}
```

my aggregation query at the moment looks like

```
aggregation query
{'$match': {key: 'value'}},
{'$project': {
            '_id': True,
            'ack.isAck': {'$cond' : [ "$ack.isAck", 1, 0 ] }
        }
},
{'$group': {
        '_id': {
            'ack': '$ack',
        },
        'count': {'$sum': 1}
    }
}
```

This query returns me 3 documents witch content is :

```
{count: 3, 'ack': {isAck: True}}
```

I don t know what is wrong and how to get only one document that looks like

```
{count: 3 'ack' : 2}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was not specifying the correct variable for the field and also cancelling the field out, but you can simplify this as well:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "key": "value" } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { "isAck": "$ack.isAck" },
        "count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$cond": [ "$ack.isAck", 1, 0 ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
       "_id": 0,
       "ack": "$_id",
       "count": 1
    }}
])
```

Or even just drop the last project if you can deal with the field being called `_id` rather than `ack` in the final result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this seems to work.
However, when the isAck key is not set, result count is set to 0 and looks like
     {'ok': 1.0, 'result': [{'count': 0, 'ack': {'isAck': None}}, {'count': 2, 'ack': {'isAck': True}}]}
what is missing to take care of the case when isAck key is not set ?